# configure Grails app to use JDBC connection pool

Tags: grails, jdbc, groovy, datasource, tomcat7

[This article](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2012/01/24/using-tomcat-7-jdbc-connection-pool-production) suggests Tomcat 7 apps should use a JDBC connection pool instead of a commons-dbcp connection pool. However, the latter is the default for a Grails app, and it's not obvious how to change it.

My guess is that I need to define a Spring bean in `resources.groovy` that overrides a bean that is normally created by default, but I've no idea what this bean should be named or what properties I need to set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would probably be to use the [jdbc-pool](http://grails.org/plugin/jdbc-pool) plugin. Since the configuration options for this pool are intentionally very similar to Commons DBCP (they're documented [here](https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html)) you can use the plugin to define the jar dependency and manage switching the class for you. The plugin hasn't been updated in a year so it's a little out of date (the plugin uses version 1.0.9.0 but the [latest is 1.0.9.3](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/detail?name=com.springsource.org.apache.tomcat.jdbc)) so you might want to define the plugin dependency excluding the jar, and add one for the newer version. It's in the `ebr` repo, so you'll need to add that to your BuildConfig.groovy (see the [plugin's version](http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-jdbc-pool/tags/LATEST_RELEASE/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy) for how he did it).

There are configuration notes for the pool [here](https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) and a series of blog posts by the author [here](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/tags/connection-pool).

If you do want to configure this without using the plugin, add the `ebr` repo and the jar dependency to `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
repositories {
   inherits true
   ...
   ebr()
}

dependencies {
   runtime('org.apache.tomcat:com.springsource.org.apache.tomcat.jdbc:1.0.9.3') {
      transitive = false
   }
}
```

and create an override for the `dataSource` bean in `resources.groovy`:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource

beans = {

   dataSource(DataSource) {
      // mandatory
      driverClassName = '${dataSource.driverClassName}'
      username = '${dataSource.username}'
      password = '${dataSource.password}'
      url = '${dataSource.url}'
      // optional
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
      numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
      testOnBorrow=true
      testWhileIdle=true
      testOnReturn=true
      validationQuery="SELECT 1"
   }
}
```

It's convenient to use single-quoted strings with `${}` placeholders to take advantage of Spring's property placeholder functionality and keep things DRY since you've already set the driver and connect info in `DataSource.groovy`.

Comment: I think I'll just use the plugin. I'll do a new release of it, that upgrades to the latest version of the JDBC connection pool lib.

Answer (score 3):

In `DataSource.groovy` I use the following:

```
environments {
    integration {
        dataSource {
            pooled = false
            jndiName = "java:/comp/env/jdbc/myJndiName"
        }
    }
 }
```

And everything else is defined by Tomcat - this just needs to match it. There is no need to define any dataSource bean in `resources.groovy`

Comment: Ah, your question didn't mention development mode.

Comment: I want my development env to be as similar as possible to production to minimise the potential for surprises