# How do I update the Solr version in grails-solr-plugin without affecting the plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins, solr

We are using solr-grails plugin for our website. And the most recent version of the plugin (grails-solr-plugin 0.2) uses solr 1.4, whereas the latest version of Solr is 3.5.
Is there any way I can update the Solr version without affecting the plugin?
Kindly help.

Comment: **Help Please??!! Anybody???**

Comment: **OK, OK, keep you pants on, I'm coming**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install the plugin, excluding the version of the Solr library therein, then explicitly include the more recent version. The details are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550700/configure-grails-app-to-use-jdbc-connection-pool) in the context of another plugin.

Assuming you already have a plugin developer account, it would probably be easier to just download the plugin source code, upgrade the library and release a new version. FYI, a new plugin version can be released by anyone, not just the original plugin author. Your fellow Solr plugin users will thank you for this.

Comment: Agreed, but I'd post a message ahead of time on the grails-dev list just to let people know what you're doing.  For something like the solr plugin which appears to be abandoned, it would definitely be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin doesn't seem to be updated for almost a year now. There have been a number of forks from the original source code and some of them are updates for the 3.5 version - https://github.com/mbrevoort/grails-solr-plugin/network  . You should try one of those.