# What to do if database connection check fails in bootstrap?

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, database-connection, bootstrapping

I am developing an app using grails. In the bootstrap part, I am checking and initialising database connections. Suppose the database is not available due to some problem its wise to send notification to administrator. But, what to do next? Should the grails application stop automatically or wait for administrator to come and do that manually? Also, what is the way of automatically shutting down the deployed war using grails?

Comment: If Grails can't instantiate the hibernate session during startup, if I'm not mistaken, your application will be unavaliable. To determine if you need to shut down your app I think you can evaluate if the bootstrap stuff that use the database is critical for the app or not.

Comment: thanks. But, I am not using hibernate session here. I have my own connection pool (HBase connection pool) which I initialise during bootstrap process.

Comment: So I think that what you need is to change the declaration of the Spring Bean responsible by the pool, instead of creating your in bootstrap -> [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550700/configure-grails-app-to-use-jdbc-connection-pool)