# Grails connection-pooling performance issues

Tags: grails, connection-pooling, hikaricp

During performance analysis on my project, I found several issues pointing to the connection-pooling. Each query runs the following code in order to use the session factory's connection pool:

```
def sql = new Sql(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().connection())
def resultList = sql.rows(sqlQuery,parameters)
```

The very first session factory request in each thread usually takes between 200 and 300 milliseconds while subsequent queries (even identical queries) take 50-80 milliseconds.

I switched to HikariCP just for comparison, and the performance time was cut in half primarily because there was no delay in the initial connection within each thread. What would cause the first connection in each thread to take so long in the default Grails connection-pool manager (commons-dbcp connection pool according to [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550700/configure-grails-app-to-use-jdbc-connection-pool))?

Datasource:

```
    dataSource {
        pooled = true
        logSql = true
        loggingSql = true//change this to true to get hibernate logging in your console
        dialect="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect"
        driverClassName = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
        username = "notReal"
        password = "notReal"
        url = 'NOTREAL'
        pooled = true
        readOnly = true
        properties {
            initialSize = 4
            minIdle = 1
            maxIdle = 8
            maxActive = 100
            maxWait = 2000
            maxAge = 60000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=30000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
            abandonWhenPercentageFull = 50
            numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
            testOnBorrow=true
            testWhileIdle=true
            testOnReturn=true
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            validationInterval=500
        }
    }

hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
```

Grails version:

```
Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 
Version: 3.6.2.RELEASE
Platform: Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2)
```

Comment: That would be because HikariCP rocks.